# Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Plugin - Random Image in Sidebar

Tags: plugins, wp-query, loop, images

I’ve created a Custom Post Type, “Slide”, and I’m attempting to load a random slide image, with title and caption, in my sidebar. I’m using the [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/image/) for the post/slide creation. The code below is what I have in my sidebar.php – I do get a random post loaded in the sidebar (showing title and caption) but the image URL does not output/echo, just `<img src="" />`

Can anyone tell if I have ACF code wrong or maybe using the WP_Query wrong?

```
    <?php $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'slide', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'orderby' => rand
    );
    $attachment_id = get_field('slide_photo');
    $size = "medium"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    // url = $image[0];
    // width = $image[1];
    // height = $image[2];

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        echo '<img src="';
        echo $image[0];
        echo '" />';
        the_title();
        the_field('slide_credit');

    endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure get_field('slide_photo') returns an image ID as opposed to an object or url. What do you get when you var_dump $attachment_id? What do you get when you var_dump $image?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention, I have the slide_photo field set to image ID, not object or URL.

Comment: `var_dump ($attachment_id);` outputs: string(58) "http://path- to-image". 58 being the post id and path-to-image is the full path on my site.

Comment: `var_dump ($image);` outputs: bool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting an image because you are calling the image field outside the query loop.

```
<?php $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'slide', 
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'orderby' => rand
);

// url = $image[0];
// width = $image[1];
// height = $image[2];

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $attachment_id = get_field('slide_photo');
    $size = "medium"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );

    echo '<img src="';
    echo $image[0];
    echo '" />';
    the_title();
    the_field('slide_credit');

endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Hmmm...tried that to no avail. Still no image url output :(

Comment: Doh! Looks like in troubleshooting I had actually changed the return value from “ID” to “URL”. All is working now (with moving the code as you suggested, which I had tried before, but after having changed the return value and forgetting).